# Parsing HTML tags when echoing in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use fineDiff (http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php) to display the difference between two strings. However, I'm having an issue wherein any HTML tags ( **and**  in this case), do not seem to be parsed when echoing. Instead, they are just printed out without taking effect.

For example, comparing the difference between two strings:

Old: **E-4:** RangersLTW (DSS) [Adi] {DNQGBV+S} 15 Jul 15 **^**

New: **E-4:** RangersLTW (DSS) [Adi] {ENQGBV+S} 15 Jul 15 **^**

Find the differences like so:

```
$opcodes = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($old, $new);
$string = FineDiff::renderDiffToHTMLFromOpcodes($old, $opcodes);
```

And then echo them with `echo $string;`. However, this displays the following:

```
<b>E-4</b>: RangersLTW (DSS) [Adi] {DENQGBV+S} 15 Jul 15 <b>^</b> <b></b> <b></b>
```

Without actually making the two parts that should be bold, bold. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can get this to display?

Thanks.

Comment: View the source of the page. Does it look something like this `&lt;b&gt;E-4&lt;/b&gt;: RangersLTW (DSS) [Adi] {DENQGBV+S} 15 Jul 15 &lt;b&gt;^&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt;` ?

Comment: Yes, however the D and the E have the <del> and <ins> tags around them correctly.

Comment: Have you try `echo htmlspecialchars_decode($string)` ?

Comment: I did try it, but I made the mistake of adding htmlspecialchars first and then doing it. Doing just that works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you well this can help you:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
echo str_get_html('<b>E-4</b>: RangersLTW (DSS) [Adi] {DENQGBV+S} 15 Jul 15 <b>^</b> <b></b> <b></b>')->plaintext;
```

Here is the html_dom file location : [simple_html_dom.php](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Weirdly this removes the <ins> and <del> tags added by fineDiff but does not deal with the <b> tags.